# Data Import Export Issue C#/SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, import, linq-to-xml

I need to implement an import export module for three database tables which are internally related with primary key/foreign key constraints.

I can do both part easily using c#/linq to xml/linq to sql. Problem is, when i am importing the exported data, in database, primary key tables' id are regenerating without taking/assign the id from xml file(its natural for auto increment). For this, other tables data can't be imported/showing error that primary key constraint violates.

My goal is to import all data and keep the primary/foreign key intact.

Now, can anyone please suggest me what I can do to solve this issue please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [identity insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) to specify a value for identity columns.

If you specify explicit values for identity columns, you yourself are responsible for resolving conflicts.  If the database already has a row with `id = 1`, you have to decide what to do if the import also contains `id = 1`: SQL Server will just throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

We always used BCP operations for such tasks.

Comment: +1 or SQL Server Integration Services - why reinvent the wheel over and over again??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not make your autoincrement the primary key but to have a separate primary key which can be defined somehow else... then you won't have the problem with the autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the ids in the XML and SQL to match (only the relationships) you could use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and maintain mapping from XML ids to SQL ids to insert properly foreign key columns in other tables.

Comment: I would recommend using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`

Comment: (see [this blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) as to why ...